# Simultaneous file upload to the same directory

Tags: php, file-upload

For part of my web app, I'm attempting to upload 1 file under 2 different names. The first name is the original file name that the user specified. This is to be used for reference later on in my app. The second name is an altered name (simply adding in a counter variable). For uploading a single file using move_uploaded_file($name, $path), it works like a charm. When I attempted to call one move_uploaded_file(...) after the other, only the first function would upload a file. The second function would not return an error message.

After looking online, it seemed that this could be accomplished with a loop. I placed the names and the paths in an array, loop through it with a foreach loop but only the first file is uploaded.

Below are the files and their relevant portions as some are lengthy.

mainPage.php applies a header across all of my pages. 
verifyFile.php is the file that does the uploading as well as verifying the bulk processing to check that the file is valid.

**workPage.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require("mainPage.php");

?> 
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "CSS/workpageCSS.css" />
<div id = "pageContainer">
    <form enctype = "multipart/form-data" action = "verifyFile.php" method = "post">
        <table border = "0" cellpadding = "2" cellspacing = "5">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label for = "fileName">Select file to upload</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type = "file" name = "file" id = "fileName" placeholder = "Choose file path" autofocus = "autofocus" required = "required" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type = "submit" value = "Load file" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
```

Portion of verifyFile.php that uploads the file.

**Attempt 1:**

```
<?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $dupFile = appendFileName(basename($_FILES['file']['name']));
$origToUpload = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

$targetPath = ("uploads/".$dupFile);
$origTargetPath = "uploads/".$origToUpload;
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath)) {
    #echo("Successfully uploaded ".basename($_FILES['file']['name']));
} else {
    echo("Failed 1<br />");
}

/*move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $origTargetPath); Does not upload but no errors are generated */
?>
```

**Attempt 2**

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1')
$filesToUpload = array($targetPath, $origTargetPath);

foreach($filesToUpload as $toUpload) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $toUpload)) {
        echo("worked!"); /* first time is successful and $targetPath is loaded onto my server */
    } else {
        echo("neg"); /* nothing is uploaded and returns neg */
    }
}
?>
```

$origTargetPath and $targetPath are both valid since if I reverse them in my array, only the first file is correctly uploaded.

For additional information, I'm using Apache via XAMPP.

Comment: @Prix Sorry for the delaeyd response, just got back to my desk. Using the full path didn't change anything but I opted for Anthony Garcia's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `move_upload_file`, php will *move* the file from the file temporary location, to the one you specified. So you can't *move* the file twice.

What you are looking for is the [copy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) function. In your case (first attempt):

```
copy($targetPath, $origTargetPath);
```

You could also consider [symlink](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.symlink.php)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, just got back to my desk, tried out your suggestion and it worked beautifully!